# Using ogr2ogr to Export from Access to CSV (or Oracle)

Tags: csv, ogr2ogr, table, oracle-dbms, ms-access

I received a an Access database too many observations to simply export as a CSV by either the export buttons in Access or copying and pasting.  I tried using ogr2ogr and only get the headers in my "test.csv" file.  What am I doing wrong here?

Conversely, if possible, I'd like to import the table into Oracle.  Is there a method to do that straight from Access?

```
   ogr2ogr -update -overwrite -nlt none -progress -f CSV 'G:\Office\Heritage\KDFWR SWG Grant Work\2016_data_share\test.csv' 'G:\Office\Heritage\KDFWR SWG Grant Work\2016_data_share\Data Share\ALL_STWG.mdb'
```

Comment: Is there more than one table in the Access database?

Comment: Yes, there are 3.

Comment: It might help to specify, in the command line, what table you want to export to the CSV. I noticed the source table was missing in your command. You can get a list using the `ogrinfo` utility. And if that CSV is being created on output, it might not be necessary to add the `update` and `overwrite` flags.

Comment: The table I want to output is in the above command line:  "G:\\\\ALL_STWG.MDB "  It could be that I'm just writing it incorrectly or not referencing it properly.

Comment: Sorry, but is just looks like ALL_STWG.MDB is the Access database, and not the specific table that's inside that mdb. Does `ogrinfo -ro -al ALL_STWG.MDB` output a list of tables?

Comment: Looks like I did have my data base name wrong:  Should be 'KSNPC ALL STWG.mdb'.  ALL_STWG is the table I want to output.  The command line above worked without having to specify a table.  In other words, it exported first table out of the database.  How would I specify the table to export the other two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're first attempt (example in your question) needs to be adjusted to instead provide the name of the original Access database then the table within.

A pseudo example looks like:

`ogr2ogr -nlt none -progress -f CSV output.csv input.mdb source_table`

And specifically for your case:

`ogr2ogr -nlt none -progress -f CSV 'G:\Office\Heritage\KDFWR SWG Grant Work\2016_data_share\test.csv' 'G:\Office\Heritage\KDFWR SWG Grant Work\2016_data_share\Data Share\KSNPC ALL STWG.mdb' ALL_STWG`